# What files should be copied to make a bootable backup drive for OS X?

Tags: macos, backup, rsync

I've got an external hard drive and I'd like to create a full, bootable backup of my hard drive onto it.  I'm running Mac OS X 10.4 (Tiger).  I'd like to perform this backup from the command line, using rsync.

A typical command for backing up my entire HD to the external drive would be something like this:

```
rsync -sometags / /volumes/iMacHomeBackup
```

However, this isn't a reasonable command to run.  Many folders shouldn't be copied onto an external HD, because OS X modifies them according to the present state of the system.  As far as I can tell /Network should be left off, using the --exclude tag, as should /Volumes.

Am I right in assuming that these shouldn't be copied?  Would the copied files still result in a bootable drive?  What other folders should be left off?  Consider /dev, any swap files, and temp files.

Would any special rsync tags aide me in accomplishing my goal of creating a "perfect, bootable backup drive?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a great resource.

http://www.bombich.com/mactips/image.html

Answer (score 1):

rsync should be able to do what you're talking about, but if you want a dead simple way to make a bootable drive, try [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/software/ccc.html).

Comment: CCC worked some serious magic on when I tried to use it, and I had to exchange the fried drive for a new one.  Though it might be unreasonable, I'd like to stay away from CCC, even though it's based in rsync.

Comment: I just used CCC yesterday to clone a 120 GB drive onto a new 500GB. I swapped the new 500 in, and it booted with absolutely no issues (MacBook Pro)

Comment: I too have had great success with CCC.